# GitLab username in URL for clone

Tags: gitlab

How do I configure the GitLab URL username?

Why is the username in the Git clone URL always `git@url`?

Even if we create own user it still says `git`.

I have created my ssh key and added to the GitLab, but still it says `git@url`.

Answer (score 0):

It does say `git` because it is the account under which GitLab *server* has been installed.

It is defined in the [`gitlab.yml` config file](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/526b28daa3837209a638c1c02aed3a5371e62ee3/config/gitlab.yml.example#L38-L39).

```
# Uncomment and customize if you can't use the default user to run GitLab 
  (default: 'git')
# user: git
```

You will always contact GitLab ssh with that user 'git': that SSH session will use your public SSH key, and that will allow the GitLab server to authenticate you.

Since it is an SSH URL, you need to open a (non-interactive) **[`ssh` (secure shell)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell)** session *always* with the account git, which will have your public SSH key registered.

Comment: I am bit confused , i have created ssh key for my own user. Why will git user use my ssh key ? Its strange implementation done in gitlab or we are spoiled by github ?

Comment: Github also uses git. It uses your account name for https url, not ssh one. For ssh, you must use the server account where your public key has been registered. This isn't linked to GitLab or GitHub, but to how ssh works.